# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException when app is in network

Tags: c#, smtp

So I was trying to send an email in my app with some standard code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "mail.mycompany.es";
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "somepass");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("somemail@gmail.com"));
mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.es");
mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
client.Send(mail);
```

And it worked in debug mode, so then I released it and placed the .exe on a shared drive.

If I execute it from there, it gives me the following exception:

[System.Net.Sockets.SocketException] = {"An invalid argument was supplied"}

So it must be some kind of permissions error, but I don't know how can I solve it.

Full exception dump:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Error al enviar correo.
>
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha proporcionado un argumento no válido
>
> en System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily,
>   SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
>
> en System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6)
>
> en System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean
>   async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
>
> en System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
>
> en System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
>
> en System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)
>
> en System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)
>
> en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
>
> en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>
> --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
>
> en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>
> en Isaval.Produccion.AprovisionarViewModel.EnviarSolicitud(Object
>   obj) en 
>   c:\Users\myuser\Documents\VS\Produccion\Produccion\AprovisionarViewModel.cs:línea
>   36

Comment: Is there an inner exception with more information? Are you running it directly out of the network share?

Comment: @RonBeyer I updated the question with the full dump. Yes, I'm running it from the network drive.